# Raise exception if ArgumentParser encounters unknown argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm using the Python (version 3.9.4) library `argparse` to parse a small number of option flags. For a number of reasons, I'd like to handle errors in my code rather than `argparse.ArgumentParser`. Namely, how an unrecognized argument is handled. For example, if I ran `my-python-program --foobar`, I'd like to be able to catch an exception and perform work there. This testcase disables almost all of the errors I've tried, except for an invalid argument:

```
import argparse
import sys

try:
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, exit_on_error=False, usage=None)
  parser.add_argument("--help", action="store_true", default=False)
  parser.add_argument("--hello", default="Hello, world!")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  print(args.help, args.hello)

except Exception as err:
  print("a problem occurred!", file=sys.stderr)
  print(f"error: {err}", file=sys.stderr)
```

Instead, running `my-python-program --foobar` gives me:

```
usage: my-python-program [--help] [--hello HELLO]
my-python-program: error: unrecognized arguments: --foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Python `argparse` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53e6a9a7254bdcd0538580ba7d799cd453e2dca5/Lib/argparse.py#L1861), you can see that it calls `self.error` on an error. This function (at the bottom of the file), by default, prints the error message and quits. You can override this method in a subclass to raise an error instead.

```py
import argparse
import sys

class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
  """An argument parser that raises an error, instead of quits"""
  def error(self, message):
    raise ValueError(message)

try:
  parser = MyArgumentParser(add_help=False, exit_on_error=False, usage=None)
  parser.add_argument("--help", action="store_true", default=False)
  parser.add_argument("--hello", default="Hello, world!")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  print(args.help, args.hello)

except Exception as err:
  print("a problem occurred!", file=sys.stderr)
  print(f"error: {err}", file=sys.stderr)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py --foobar
a problem occurred!
error: unrecognized arguments: --foobar
```